# gdb breakpoint in shared library not working

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, shared-libraries, breakpoints

So, I have the following c program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
        char arr[20];
        //this is line 6
        strcpy(arr,"Hello, world!\n");
        printf(arr);
}
```

I compiled it using the following command:

```
gcc -g t2.c -o a2.out
```

After that I loaded it in gdb and tried setting breakpoints at line 6, at the strcpy function and at line 8. Sure enough, when setting the breakpoint at strcpy I got the following message : "Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n])". I answered "y" and got "Breakpoint 2 (strcpy) pending.".

After answering yes, and running through the program, Breakpoint 2 is never resolved, and the debugger jumps straight to Breakpoint 3 at printf.

I am using Intel syntax in my debugger. Other than that no custom settings. Can anyone tell why the Breakpoint at strcpy is never resolved?

Comment: the best way would be to break at `main`, THEN break at `strcpy` to ensure that C library is loaded (would avoid the pending breakpoint feature that I never could make work).

Comment: I tried putting a break in `main`, running the code, and putting another break at `strcpy` after the first one was reached. It returned this message `Breakpoint 2 at gnu-indirect-function resolver at 0xb7e79f00`. After continuing, the second breakpoint was never reached.

Comment: If you compile the program with the `-fno-builtin-strcpy` option, does it stop at your breakpoint?

Comment: Although it sets the breakpoint, it returns this error when the breakpoint is reached: `Breakpoint 2, __strcpy_sse2 ()
    at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy-sse2.S:1613
1613 ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/strcpy-sse2.S: No such file or directory.`

Comment: That error just means that you don't have the source code for glibc installed.  It's actually stopped correctly in this case.  `strcpy` is special because it's a micro-optimized "indirect" function, which means that the particular arch-specific implementation is chosen at first call (or maybe by `ld.so`, I forget).  I think gdb still has some problems debugging indirect functions nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Compilers such as gcc are deeply familiar with the semantics of string functions such as `strcpy`.
On x86-64 with your example, gcc 9 is generating inline assembly rather than a `strcpy` call even at
`-O0`. The breakpoint should work for most other functions.

x86-64 disassembly generated with gcc-9 (no strcpy call):

```
    0000000000000000 <main>:
       0:   48 83 ec 28             sub    rsp,0x28
       4:   48 b8 48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 77   movabs rax,0x77202c6f6c6c6548
       e:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    edi,0x1
      13:   48 89 04 24             mov    QWORD PTR [rsp],rax
      17:   b8 21 0a 00 00          mov    eax,0xa21
      1c:   48 89 e6                mov    rsi,rsp
      1f:   66 89 44 24 0c          mov    WORD PTR [rsp+0xc],ax
      24:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
      26:   c7 44 24 08 6f 72 6c 64     mov    DWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],0x646c726f
      2e:   c6 44 24 0e 00          mov    BYTE PTR [rsp+0xe],0x0
      33:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   38 <main+0x38>   34: R_X86_64_PLT32  __printf_chk-0x4
      38:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
      3a:   48 83 c4 28             add    rsp,0x28
      3e:   c3                      ret
```